# Not a coder, needing assistance

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am not a coder nor do it work in IT but I maintain an access database for our marketing reporting. This database has a VBA script in it that cycles through our report and creates separate excel files for each entity.  I have been able to copy the exact code and change it out using new table and filter references without any issues.

I tried to do it again today and I am getting an error `"Run-time error 3061 Too few parameters expected"`.  I have been looking online and everyone seems to say that the error refers to incorrect field names or a missing quote but i can't for the life of me figure it out. I double checked the table and field names and I have tried numerous combinations of quotes with no luck.  Sorry if this is a really stupid question but I am stumped.

```
Private Sub Command4_Click()

Dim ExportReportName As String
Dim ExportFileName As String
Dim FilterCriteriaString As String
Dim Filter As String
Dim SQLstring As String
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

ExportReportName = "User Retest-Partners"

SQLstring = "SELECT DISTINCT [2-5 User Retest Partners].[Owner] FROM [2-5 User Retest Partners]"
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQLstring)

If Not rs.BOF And Not rs.EOF Then
    rs.MoveFirst
    While (Not rs.EOF)

        Filter = rs.Fields("Owner")
        FilterCriteria = "[2-5 User Retest Partners].[Owner] LIKE '*" & Filter & "*'"
        ExportFileName = "U:\Marketing\Reporting\User Retest Needed\Database Exports\Manager Reporting\" & Filter & ".xls"

        DoCmd.OpenReport "User Retest-Partners", acViewPreview, , FilterCriteria, acHidden
        DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, ExportReportName, acFormatXLS, ExportFileName
        DoCmd.Close acReport, ExportReportName, acSaveNo

        rs.MoveNext
    Wend

End If
Set rs = Nothing

End Sub
```

This is the version of the code that runs:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()


Dim ExportReportName As String
Dim ExportFileName As String
Dim FilterCriteriaString As String
Dim Filter As String
Dim SQLstring As String
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

ExportReportName = "User Retest-Stores"

SQLstring = "SELECT DISTINCT [2-8 User Retest Stores].[Store Num] FROM [2-8 User Retest Stores]"
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQLstring)

If Not rs.BOF And Not rs.EOF Then
    rs.MoveFirst
    While (Not rs.EOF)

        Filter = rs.Fields("Store Num")
        FilterCriteria = "[2-8 User Retest Stores].[Clinic (Default)] LIKE '*" & Filter & "*'"
        ExportFileName = "U:\Marketing\Reporting\User Retest Needed\Database Exports\Store Reporting\" & Filter & ".xls"

        DoCmd.OpenReport "User Retest-Stores", acViewPreview, , FilterCriteria, acHidden
        DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, ExportReportName, acFormatXLS, ExportFileName
        DoCmd.Close acReport, ExportReportName, acSaveNo

        rs.MoveNext
    Wend

End If
Set rs = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Could you tell me which part(s) you change when you are using the code please?

Comment: I added the working code to my original post.  I have changed the ReportName, source table and the field i am using to filter the data.

Comment: Yes that is the line that is causing the error.

Comment: @kmmur259 That was an "or", e.g., you were supposed to choose one of the lines causing the error.

Comment: Sorry I missed the OR, the line that is highlighted in the debugger is: Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQLstring)

Comment: Thanks @HansUp, I was thinking that was the problem as well but I cut and paste the field names directly from the table AND I ran the SQL statement in access and it runs in its own query but inside of the VBA script i'm having issues.

Comment: I followed your directions above and  I used your sample name of "MyTestQuery".  I received the same error highlighting the new line: Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("MyTestQuery").

Comment: Now I'm even more confused.  Since the report contained confidential information I made a new database with bogus information with the same columns names and table names.  I cut and pasted the exact same code into the blank database and it runs perfectly!  I didn't change anything in the code.  How do I attach the file to my post? I'm new here, sorry